# chrome extension: append (push) JSON data into localStorage()

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have created my own method called pushLocalStorage() into my background.js to ease appending an object into an array of objects. It's purpose is to simply take data from the caller and if the key exists then push the data object onto the existing array stored in a previous iteration. If the key doesn't exist then create a new array indice.

The creation of the first object works fine. The second insertion successfully completed but insert the length of the array instead of the object. Finally the third and any subsequent inserts fail because the data is no longer an array but a string and my code verifies that the data is an array before inserting data. See example logging after the code:

Here's my code:

```
else if (request.method == 'pushLocalStorage')      
{
    var key; 
    var data;
    var stored;

    // if key isn't sent from caller, quit with error.
    if ( 'undefined' == typeof(request.key) )
    {
        sendResponse({success: 0,error: 'Key value was not sent from caller.'});
    }

    // if the key isn't a string type then quit with error.
    if ( 'string' != typeof(request.key) )
    {
        sendResponse({success: 0,error: 'Expected key passed from caller to be a ' + 
                                        'string but it was a(n) ' + typeof(request.key) + ' instead'});
    }

    // if data value isn't sent from caller, quit with error.
    if ( 'undefined' == typeof(request.data) )
    {
        sendResponse({success: 0,error: 'Data value was not sent from caller.'});
    }

    key    = request.key;
    data   = request.data;
    stored = localStorage.getItem(key); // attempt to retrieve existing store named by 'key'

    // Now if stored isn't null or undefined...
    if ( 'undefined' != typeof(stored) && stored != null )
    {
        // parse it back into a valid data structure from JSON
        stored = JSON.parse(stored);

        // if stored exists (should be an Array object)
        if ( stored.length )
        {
            // stored should be an array of objects so...
            for ( var i = 0 ; stored.length < i ; i++ )
            {
                // make sure not to push dupe tickets into the array. In this case, replace
                // the existing ticket with the new.
                if ( data.id === stored[i].id )
                {
                    stored[i] = data;

                    // save the data to localStorage (do not push but overwrite)
                    localStorage.setItem(key,JSON.stringify(stored));
                    test = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
                    sendResponse({success: 1,data: test});
                    return;
                }
            }

            // save the stored object back to localStorage after pushing the new data to it.
            localStorage.setItem(key,stored.push(JSON.stringify(data)));
            test = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
            sendResponse({success: 1,data: test});
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(' data would be: %o and stored was: %o', data,stored);
            sendResponse({success: 0, error: 'Attempt to coerce object into array not allowed.'});
        }
    }
    else
    {
        console.debug(' Creating new array to be stored.');
        stored = new Array(data);
        stored = JSON.stringify(stored);

        localStorage.setItem(key,stored);

        test = localStorage.getItem(key);
        test = JSON.parse(test);
        console.log('setItem.' + key + ',' + stored + '\nThe stored obj was: %o and the localStored.getItem after storage was: %o',test,localStorage.getItem(key));
        sendResponse({success: 1,data: test});
    }
}
```

In the chrome console I get the following:

```
Object  
localstorage push! [Object]:  
Object
localstorage push! [Object]:
Object
localstorage push! [Object]:
Object
localstorage push! [Object]:
Object
localstorage push! 2:  
Object
localstorage push! [Object]: 
Object
localstorage push! 2:
Object
localstorage push failed: Attempt to coerce object into array not allowed. 
Object
localstorage push failed: Attempt to coerce object into array not allowed.
Object
localstorage push! [Object]:
Object
localstorage push! 2:
Object
localstorage push failed: Attempt to coerce object into array not allowed.
```

So after trying several different methods of coding the functionality I desire, nothing seems to work. Am I barking up the wrong tree or am I just coding a poor implementation?

TIA

EDIT:

Fixed code in completion:

```
if (request.method == 'pushLocalStorage')       
{
    var key; 
    var data;
    var stored;

    // if key isn't sent from caller, quit with error.
    if ( 'undefined' == typeof(request.key) )
    {
        sendResponse({success: 0,error: 'Key value was not sent from caller.'});
    }

    // if the key isn't a string type then quit with error.
    if ( 'string' != typeof(request.key) )
    {
        sendResponse({success: 0,error: 'Expected key passed from caller to be a ' + 
                                        'string but it was a(n) ' + typeof(request.key) + ' instead'});
    }

    // if data value isn't sent from caller, quit with error.
    if ( 'undefined' == typeof(request.data) )
    {
        sendResponse({success: 0,error: 'Data value was not sent from caller.'});
    }

    key    = request.key;
    data   = request.data;
    stored = localStorage.getItem(key); // attempt to retrieve existing store named by 'key'

    // Now if stored isn't null or undefined...
    if ( 'undefined' != typeof(stored) && stored != null )
    {
        // parse it back into a valid data structure from JSON
        stored = JSON.parse(stored);

        // if stored exists (should be an Array object)
        if ( stored.length )
        {
            // stored should be an array of objects so...
            for ( var i = 0 ; i < stored.length ; i++ )
            {
                // make sure not to push dupe tickets into the array. In this case, replace
                // the existing ticket with the new.
                if ( data.id === stored[i].id )
                {
                    stored[i] = data;

                    // purge the item...
                    localStorage.removeItem(key);

                    // save the data to localStorage.
                    localStorage.setItem(key,JSON.stringify(stored));

                    data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
                    sendResponse({success: 1,data: data});
                    return;
                }
            }

            // save the stored object back to localStorage after pushing the new data to it.
            stored.push(data);
            localStorage.setItem(key,JSON.stringify(stored));
            data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
            sendResponse({success: 1,data: data});
        }
        else
        {
            sendResponse({success: 0, error: 'Attempt to coerce object into array not allowed.'});
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Figured it out. I was zigging when I should have been zagging:

Wrong:

```
localStorage.setItem(key,stored.push(JSON.stringify(data)));
```

Right:

```
stored.push(data);
localStorage.setItem(key,JSON.stringify(stored));

test = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
sendResponse({success: 1,data: test});
```

The problem was I was attempting to push a stringified value into an array object. Yeah, can't do that. Once I fixed that, all was well.

Comment: Glad you figured out a working solution, but in the spirit of completeness and posterity, there isn't anything wrong with pushing a stringified value into an array object. The problem you had appears to be that you were trying to push the returned value from `stored.push(...)`, which returns the new length of the array. For example, `[1,1,2,3,5,8].push(13)` will return 7, since, after the push, there are seven items in the array.